# Add default portlet to a content-type programmatically via python

Tags: plone

I've to setup via python a specific portlet to a specific content-type.

I'm reading plone.app.portlets to understand how plone can make this TTW but I cannot figure out how solve my problem.

I couldn't use genericsetup because this behavior is linked to a choice of a user in a generic configlet of my product.

How?

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

Google says that this could be your solution: http://www.scarba05.co.uk/blog/2010/12/copy-portlets-assigned-to-one-item-to-another-programatically-in-plone/ :)